# Configuration file not found: /path/to/rubocop.yml

Tags: ruby, macos, vim, rubocop

I saved the file [rubocop.vim](https://github.com/ngmy/vim-rubocop/blob/master/plugin/rubocop.vim) in `~/.vim/plugin/`, and when I run `:Rubocop` in Vim I get

> Configuration file not found: /path/to/rubocop.yml.

I couldn't find the path to rubocop.yml.

I am on MacOS Mojave.

Thank you.

Comment: Does it say that literally? Did you customize the path to the `.yml` file?

Comment: like @tadman says, there is a rubocop.yml file. Where is it? You need to tell VIM where this yml file is.

Comment: @tadman where should I find rubocop.yml?

Comment: @tadman I see, I learned that I should have a rubocop.yml in the same root path of the files that I am fixing. 
PLEASE, correct me if I am wrong. Thank you!

Comment: You can have it per-project, or you can have it set for all projects by putting that in your home directory. It's really up to you. Normally having a `~/.rubocop/rubocop.yml` is a sensible default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Vim8 it is more convenient to use the new "package" feature. This topic has been already covered over here:
[vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9522/what-is-the-vim8-package-feature-and-how-should-i-use-it](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9522/what-is-the-vim8-package-feature-and-how-should-i-use-it)

`.rubocop.yml` is included in the `Rubocop` public repository.

```
git clone git@github.com:rubocop-hq/rubocop.git
```